# I need help fixing "You've broken the reference to the CDN. "

Tags: cdn

I posted the following question and the tech responded with this:

(You've broken the reference to the CDN. Please ask for help on the forums or Stack Overflow if you're still confused about what's wrong.)

I have no idea how to fix this, can someone please help?

This was my issue:

The Tabs Function has stopped working on my website. I have used it for over a year and this has never been the case. The tabs appear, but then you have to double click them to get them to show up.

This is the error:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery-ui.css, line 0) http://edgeendo.com/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?ver=3.4.2

You can view the tabs on the resources page, several product pages, etc.

This page is specifically affected:

http://edgeendo.com/resources/#mt-tab-nsai

Please advise.

Thanks,

Jessey

Comment: That's not the correct URL. See how it's been appended to your domain name? It's not `http://edgeendo.com//ajax.googleapis.com/...`, it's `http://ajax.googleapis.com/...`.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to load the `jquery-ui` code from an address at `edgeendo.com` but the address you need is actually on Google's servers. The correct address is http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css?ver=3.4.2   but somehow `edgeendo.com` has been prepended to it. Remove the unwanted extra.